# How do you manually construct a lambda expression?

Tags: linq, lambda, linq-to-entities, expression

I'm designing an application using ASP.NET Web API and Entity Framework 5 and LINQ to Entities. The Web API doesn't serve up the entities directly, it converts them to a set of data transfer objects that are similar but not identical to my entities. The API will be used by a Silverlight application initially but I will have to support non-.NET clients (e.g. iOS apps) down the road. I'd also like to give the client the ability to run a robust set of queries against the API.

These requirements have lead me to consider the query object pattern. Essentially, I want to create a homegrown query object client-side, post it to the Web API, and convert the query object to a lambda expression that I can use in LINQ to Entities. This last part is what's tripping me up.

Starting with a simple comparison query, I want to be able to convert an object that looks like the following into a lambda expression at runtime.

```
public enum QueryOperator
{
    None = 0,
    GreaterThan,
    GreaterThanOrEqualTo,
    EqualTo,
    NotEqualTo,
    LessThanOrEqualTo,
    LessThan
}

public class SimpleQuery<T>
{
    public SimpleQuery()
    {
        this.Field = null;
        this.Operator = QueryOperator.None;
        this.Value = null;
    }

    public string Field { get; set; }
    public QueryOperator Operator { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<T> Execute(IQueryable<T> queryTarget)
    {
        // ????
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Web API supports native querying capabilities for types that you expose as IQueryable. Any client (including iOs) can use the common query syntax set-up with WCF Data Services through the URI for filtering/projection/paging/etc. Why reinvent the wheel here?

Comment: This is true, but (to the best of my knowledge) it only supports very simple queries via the $filter parameter.  I'm going to need more robust querying functionality than this offers such as returning entities based on the value of a related entity, i.e. joining.  As far as I know, Web API doesn't support this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to do things like this in the past. Here's what I came up with:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Execute(IQueryable<T> queryTarget)
{
    return queryTarget.Where(this.GetWhereExpression<T>());
}

private Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetWhereExpression<T>()
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var prop = Expression.Property(param, this.Field);
    var value = Expression.Constant(this.Value, prop.Type);
    Expression compare = null;
    switch(this.Operator) 
    {
        case QueryOperator.EqualTo:
            compare = Expression.Equal(prop, value);
            break;
        ...
    }

    return Expression.Lambda(compare, param);
}
```